# JsonConfigurationSource/JsonConfigurationProvider

Tags: c#, json, configuration

I need to collect some application configurations using this code that has a return of type IConfiguration:

```
var jsonConfigurationSource = new JsonConfigurationSource();
jsonConfigurationSource.Path = sourcePath;
jsonConfigurationSource.ReloadOnChange = true;
jsonConfigurationSource.Optional = false;
var jsonConfigurationProvider = new JsonConfigurationProvider(jsonConfigurationSource);
configProvider.Load(ConvertStringToStream(data.Data));
return new ConfigurationBuilder().Add(jsonConfigurationSource).Build();
```

The problem is that always I got this execption

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'C:\Projects...\appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.'

Can someone help me to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the properties of .json file to Copy Always- which means that this file will go to bin/ folder every-time you build. After that rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this too even when the appsettings.json file was definitely in the bin/ folder. Turned out to be some issue with permissions - the bin folder couldn't be deleted even though my Windows profile owned the folder and contents.  Adding user Everyone to bin/ with full permissions and a restart allowed me to delete bin/, followed by dotnet clean.  Then the error disappeared.